# Script .files.length works fine with IE but gives error in Chrome

Tags: javascript

```js
function uploadFile(btn) {
  if (btn.files.length != 0) {
    var test = document.getElementById("<%=btnUpload.ClientID%>");
    test.disabled = false;
    $(".aspNetDisabled").addClass('enabled');
  } else {
    var txt = document.getElementById("<%=btnUpload.ClientID%>");
    txt.disabled = true;
    $(".aspNetDisabled").removeClass('enabled');
  }
}
```

Comment: what is `btn` ? And if it's an `<input>`, what is its `type` ?

Comment: what is the error ?

Answer (score 0):

Good morning button is a type of input. If you want make some buttons you must give you input type button. for inputs you can use other type, like mail, like password or text.

In you example btn - is a button.